# R言語　for文での変数名の変更について

Tags: r

R言語でのfor文の変数名の変更の仕方が分かりません。
例えば，，，data_01,data_02,data_03　があり，

```
for(i in 1:2){
       data_i<-data_i+1
｝
```

このようにしたいのですが，やり方が分かりません。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 配列などを使うのでは駄目なのでしょうか……？

Comment: 無事解決しました！！
ありがとうございました。

因みにassign(),get()を使いました。

Comment: 良かったです :) スタック・オーバーフローでは[回答を承認することができる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)ので、お試し下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` と `assign()` を使う方法です。

```
data_01 <- 1
data_02 <- 2
data_03 <- 3

print(c(data_01, data_02, data_03))
for(i in 1:3){
  nth <- paste0("data_", formatC(i, width=2, flag="0"))
  assign(nth, get(nth) + 1)
}
print(c(data_01, data_02, data_03))

=>
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

そのような時は、ぜひRの醍醐味である「ベクトル」を使ってみて下さい

```
data <- NULL

for(i in 1:2){
    data[i] <- i
}

print(data)
```

このような出力が得られます。

```
> data
[1] 1 2
```

こうするメリットは、要素の数が増えてもコードは増えない事です：

```
data <- NULL

for(i in 1:100){
    data[i] <- i
}

print(data)
```

全く同じコードで、データが増えても処理できます。

```
> data
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
 [20]  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38
 [39]  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57
 [58]  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76
 [77]  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95
 [96]  96  97  98  99 100
```

このように格納されていると、任意の場所だけを切り出すのも、とってもラクちんです。

```
> data[10:15]
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

最後に、Rは各種ベクトル演算が他のどの言語よりも短く簡素に書ける言語です。

```
data <- 1:100
```

ご質問の処理は、これだけで完了できますよ

Answer (score 0):

`eval`で文字列を実行してくれます。
`data_01`のように数字が0埋めされているのであれば、for文の中の`i`を`formatC(i, width=2, flag=0)`に変えればOKです。

```
for (i in 1:2){
    eval(parse(text = paste0('data_', i, '<- data_', i, '+ 1')))
}
```